# How to roughly translate site pageviews to its potential revenue from ads?

Tags: advertising

I know it depends greatly on each individual case, but lets say some site is doing 100k unique pageviews a day, how to estimate approximate potential monthly revenues from banners on such site (in average case scenario)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with spaetzel to the extent that you're talking about CPC advertising. But, in terms of CPM advertising, it's easier to figure out.

Many entry-level ad networks pay $0.50 to $1 per 1000 ad impressions. So, for a site with 100,000 page views per day, you're talking about $50-$100. Double it if you have two ad units; triple if you have three; etc.

It also depends, of course, on who your audience is. If your users are attractive to advertisers you'll be able to charge much higher CPMs.

Comment: As I understand it is worst case scenario?

Comment: Yes, that's about right.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to say. The criteria for determining if people will click on an ad depends on many factors including site layout and content.

Just try Googling [Adsense layout suggestions](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=adsense+layout+suggestions&qscrl=1) and you'll see many people spend a lot of time experimenting to get people to click on more ads.

Basically, to answer your question, you need to experiment to see how much you can earn with ads and modify your site in various ways to maximise your revenue.

Comment: Can we just take average click statistics?

Answer (score 2):

Not only does it depend on the layout of your page, but also the content of your page, and the people your page is targeting.  (AdWords users have the option to only display ads to people from certain locations)

Answer (score 1):

Not only does it depend on the content of the page and the layout of the page but also the content of the ads. With Adsense you can tune the ads to the content to maximize their effectiveness. Check the google adsense customization.